# Asterisk Freepbx - hide external number on user's display after forwarding

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

For some reason I can not find the necessary information on the Internet.

Subscriber A has set forwarding to an external number (output to the city goes through a sip trunk). I want this external number to be hidden for subscriber B, when he calls subscriber A.

How to implement?

Those. In my understanding there should be a condition:

If the call was forwarded and a call was made to a number that starts with _11X (exit to the city) Then perform the callerid replacement function.
####################################################################

Update:

Perhaps I explained incorrectly.
For example, I call from number 2222 to number 3333 (these numbers are located on Asterisk). Call forwarding to mobile number 11444555566 is set on number 3333 (Calls to external numbers go through sip trunk to siemens)

So, when I call like this, I see that the call goes to number 3333, but when the mobile number 11444555566 answers, then I see this number 11444555566 on the my phone, but I would not want it to be visible on the display, because we consider mobile number information to be private.

And I would like to hide this number only if forwarding to numbers _11 is set

On FreePBX, I can make a custom dialplan in extensions_custom.conf, but I need a hint.

for example, I now have a simple dialplan for external outgoing calls in extensions_custom, i want to hide ${EXTEN} on the phone display:

```
[dial-siemens]
exten => _11.,1,Set(CALLERID(num)=${CALLERID(num)})
exten => _11.,n,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN}@Siemens,120)
exten => _11.,n,Hangup()
```

####################################################################

UPDATE:

I continued to look for a solution and something worked, but not completely.
It turned out to remove the number from the phone display with such a dialplan setting, the **I** option helped.

```
exten => _11X.,1,Set(CONNECTEDLINE(num)=fwd to external)
exten => _11X.,n,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN}@Siemens,,I)
exten => _11X.,n,Hangup()
```

Now, when dialing an external number _11, I see "fwd to external" instead of the number. This is what I need.

Now I need to make the rule only run when the call has been redirected. Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to work like that:

```
[dial-siemens]
exten => _11X.,1,ExecIf($["${DB(CF/${CONNECTEDLINE(num)})}"!=""]?Macro(dial-siemens-cf-external,${EXTEN}),s,1)
exten => _11X.,n,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN}@Siemens,120)
exten => _11X.,n,Hangup()

[macro-dial-siemens-cf-external]
exten => s,1,Set(CONNECTEDLINE(num)=fwd to external)
exten => s,n,Dial(PJSIP/${ARG1}@Siemens,,I)
exten => s,n,Hangup()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in do anything like that.

If you have DID forwarded to asterisk PBX and customer A call to that did - there is no any way for customer know where call was send. External number, sip device, artifact intelligence system, conference etc - all will looks the same. Customer should know only DID's number.

If you need customer B not know callerid of customer A, you just should replace CALLERID on the router you are using to call B. I.e put one of your did in CALLERID field at outbound routes and select "force callerid".

Hint: You can have multiple outbound rules per trunk, with different prefixes.

Comment: You have hint in the answer above. You don't need custom dialplan in FreePBX for that.

Comment: sorry, maybe I didn’t understand, but I don’t see any changes if I enter the Outbound CID at the subscriber or choose Force Trunk CID in the Siemens trunk

Comment: Maybe your trunk not allow change CID at all. No idea. See how to debug asterisk-sip etc. Anyway not see how I can improve answer. https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Collecting+Debug+Information